# Swift trying to cross check array of SKActions with array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Hi I'm trying to pick an `SKAction` from an array of SKAction's by using a string.

I have an array with all my game's possible SKActions in it. I then need to pull out the particular actions that match a selected node's possible action names (strings).

So, for example, I might have

```
allActions = [runCentre, runLeft, runRight]
```

whereby those are SKActions, and

```
possibleActions = [runCentre, runRight]
```

which are strings accessed from a property list relating to the given node type.

How do I query the allActions array for the values in possibleActions? I know the mechanics of iterating through both arrays but not what I would actually try to access. Can I give the SKActions a string property somehow? I tried

```
runStraight.setValue("runStraight", forKey: "name")
```

but that throws up `NSUnknownKeyException`. Is there a better way to do this?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't understand very well what do you want to achieve.
Unfortunately a `SKAction` don't have a **tag** or **name** property as identification. 
You can create a dictionary to associate a string key to a `SKAction`

Suppose you have these actions:

```
let runCentre = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:100.0,y:100.0), duration: 1.0)
let runLeft = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0,y:100.0), duration: 1.0)
let runRight = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:200.0,y:100.0), duration: 1.0)
let runTop = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:100.0,y:200.0), duration: 1.0)
let runBottom = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:100.0,y:0.0), duration: 1.0)
// create a dictionary (key:string, value:SKAction)
let allActions = ["runCentre":runCentre,"runLeft":runLeft,"runRight": runRight,"runTop":runTop,"runBottom":runBottom]
```

You can build a dictionary with:

```
let allActions = ["runCentre":runCentre,"runLeft":runLeft,"runRight": runRight,"runTop":runTop,"runBottom":runBottom]
```

Now suppose you have a node with these possible actions:

```
let runDiag = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0,y:200.0), duration: 1.0)
let possibleActions = ["runCentre":runCentre, "runRight": runRight, "runDiag":runDiag]
```

To know what `possibleActions` are available in `allActions` (relying on equal keys) you could do:

```
let availableActions = allActions.filter { possibleActions.keys.contains($0.key) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the list of all actions in a dictionary of type `[String:SKAction]`.

```
let allActions = [
    "runCenter": runCenter,
    "runLeft": runLeft,
    // etc
]
```

If you have a node's possible actions in a `String` array, you could use (flat)Map.

```
let possibleActions = ["runCenter", "idle"]

let possibleSKActions = possibleActions.flatMap { allActions[$0] }

// or if we are sure the action names will always have a value
let possibleSKActions = possibleActions.map { allActions[$0]! }
```